# What does it mean that a field can be a vector space in itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The commutative field $K$ can be considered a **vector space** in itself.

I define a series of properties common to fields and vector spaces and then define each of these separately and guide how I am understanding both concepts. **Some properties of algebraic structures common to vector spaces and fields are:**

${\color{red}{\text{- Internal binary operation:}}}$

$A×A→A$
$(a,b)→a⋆b$

${\color{red}{\text{- External operation:}}}$

$A×B \to A$
$A×B \to C$
$B×A \to A$
$A×A \to B$

${\color{red}{\text{- Neutral element: a number within the set in use that, operated with any other number in the set, does not alter it.}}}$

$\exists~0 \in V: \forall~v\in V: v+0=0+v=v~~{\text{for all}}~~ v∈V. ~{\text{Neutral element}}$.

${\color{red}{\text{- Commutative property: the order of the values does not alter the result.}}}$

$∀~u,v \in V:u+v=v+u$

${\color{red}{\text{- Associative property: the order of operation does not alter the result.}}}$

$∀~u,v,w  ∈V,(u+v)+w=u+(v+w)$

${\color{red}{\text{- Opposite element: is a number of the set that, operated on another number of the set, results in the neutral element.}}}$

$∀~u∈V \exists~-u∈V: u+(-u)=(-u)  +u=\overrightarrow 0 $

${\color{red}{\text{- Distributive property: given 2 operations (for example: + , * ∈ A) the first will be distributive with respect to the second, if it is distributive to the left and to the right for any 3 elements: a, b, c ∈ A.}}}$

$∀~a,b,c ∈ A,(a\ast b)\circ c=(a\circ c)\ast (b\circ c), c\circ (a\ast b)=(c\circ a)\ast (c\ast b)$

**Vector space.**

Is an algebraic structure created from a non-empty set, an internal operation (called sum, defined for the elements of the set) and an external operation (called product by a scalar, defined between said set and another set, with body structure).

A vector space always has a field K on which it is defined, being in itself a triple $(V,+,\bullet)$ that satisfies:

•   There is an **“addition”** operation that takes values **$u~$** and **$~v$** that belong to **$V$** and the addition operation gives **$u+v$** that belongs to **$V$**.

•   There is a **“multiplication”** operation that takes values **$\lambda$** that belongs to **$K$** and **$u$** that belongs to **V**, giving as a result **$\lambda u$** that also belongs to **$V$**.

In both cases the operations **“addition”** and **“multiplication”** are not those referred to real numbers, in this case the notation used + and ∙ refer specifically to the operations applied to the vector space **$V$** and relations with a field **$K$**. The elements of the vector space are called vectors and are represented as $u,v,w$,..., while the elements of the field will be called scalars and are represented as Greek letters
$\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\mu$. Therefore, vectors can be added and subtracted from each other and can also be multiplied by scalars, complying with the usual algebraic properties. Vector spaces also have the following fundamental properties:

•   Sum (+):

- Neutral element.
- Commutative property.
- Associative property.
- Opposite element.
- Distributive property.

•   Product (∙):

- Associative property.
- Distributive property.
- Neutral element.

**Field.**

Algebraic structures that satisfy the form (B,⋆,△) where B is the set for which the two operations are defined (⋆,△). Fulfilling for .

(⋆) with:

- Commutative property.
- Symmetric element.
- Neutral element.
- Associative property.
- Internal binary operation.

(△) with:

- Internal binary operation.
- Associative property.

With both operations the distributive property is verified.
I imagine a vector space as a set of vectors and a field, intuitively, as a set of numbers, if so and in both cases (vector space and body) respectively fulfilling the properties described for each one.

If my previous statement is true: **how is it possible to consider a field as a vector space? Could it be due to the coincidence between properties?** or is it a particular case of some vector space? In that last case, if a practical example were provided it would be of great help.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with $\mathbb R^n$.  What would $\mathbb R^1$ look like?

Comment: Every field is a one dimensional vector space over itself, as you say.

Comment: I like to separate vectors and scalars notationally for this reason. For example take $\alpha , x \in K$ with $\alpha$ a scalar and $x$ a vector. It makes it a little easier to see why this is true.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have put it together already, but just for concreteness:

A field has defined multiplication and addition, with both being commutative and associative, having inverses and identities, and with multiplication distributing over addition. A vector space can be thought of as an abelian group with defined multiplication by a field which distributed over the group operation. If we take the additive group of a field as our abelian group, we can use multiplication by the field as our vector space scalar multiplication.

So it might be termed a "coincidence", but it's more just that fields with addition and multiplication already satisfy the requisite commutativity and distributive axioms.